# Javascript while loop terminating without executing the statement

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I want my program should work like: it should ask user for the answer over and over until correct answer and at the end alert with well done message.

Any help why it isn't woking that way????

```
var answer = prompt('What is the capital of Pakistan?');
while(answer != 'islamabad'){
  if(answer === 'islamabad'){
    alert('Your answer is correct!');
  }else if(answer != 'islamabad'){
    answer = prompt('Try again.');
  }else{
    alert('Well Done');
  }
}
```

Comment: `prompt` & `alert` = Blocking UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition `if(answer === 'islamabad')` will never be true: you are checking `if == islamabad` after a condition which checks `if != islamabad`

```
while(answer != 'islamabad'){
    if(answer === 'islamabad'){   ◄ this will never be true
```

Try using the following:

```
var answer = prompt('What is the capital of Pakistan?');
while(answer != 'islamabad'){       
    answer = prompt('Try again.');
}
alert('Well Done');
```